# DB Java Connection NullPointerException

Tags: java, database, database-connection, mysql-workbench

Ok, So for some reason I keep getting a nullPointerException when trying to connect to my mySQL database. I was told to run my DbSetup file to see what errors I get and this is what I get

```
 Apr 04, 2018 9:10:37 PM my.pack.DbConnection getNewStatement
ERROR: Problem with DB connection:
SEVERE: ERROR: Problem with DB connection: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at my.pack.collection.createItemTable(collection.java:29)
    at my.pack.DbSetup.main(DbSetup.java:17)
C:\Users\Anastasia\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

This physical file for DbSetup is:

```
public class DbSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        collection.createItemTable();  ***null error here***

        itemBean testItem = new itemBean("itemCode", "song", "artist","category",
        "description", "songURL", "rating");
        collection.addItem(testItem);

        UserDB uDB = new UserDB();
        uDB.createUserTable();

        User testUser = new User("userID", "firstName", "lastName", "email",
        "address", "city", "state",
        "zipcode", "country");
        uDB.addUser(testUser);
    }
}
```

the collection file which is called by the DbSetup

```
import java.util.*;
 import java.sql.*;
 import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class collection{

    public static void createItemTable(){
         Statement statement = DbConnection.getNewStatement();

        try {
            statement.execute("CREATE TABLE item("  //    **************error here** **************
                    + "`itemCode` VARCHAR(255),`song` VARCHAR(255),"
                    + "`artist` VARCHAR(255),`category` VARCHAR(255),"
                    + "`description` VARCHAR(8000),`songURL` VARCHAR(255), `rating` VARCHAR(255)"
                    + "PRIMARY KEY (itemCode))");
            System.out.println("Created a new table: " + "ITEM");
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            if (se.getErrorCode() == 30000 && "X0Y32".equals(se.getSQLState())) {
                // we got the expected exception when the table is already there
            } else {
                // if the error code or SQLState is different, we have an unexpected exception
                System.out.println("ERROR: Could not create ITEM table: " + se);
            }
        }

    }
    public static itemBean addItem(String itemCode, String song, String artist,
            String category, String description, String songURL, String rating){
       Connection connection = DbConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps;
        // insert the new row into the table
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO item VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            ps.setString(1, itemCode);
            ps.setString(2, song);
            ps.setString(3, artist);
            ps.setString(4, category);
            ps.setString(5, description);
            ps.setString(6, songURL);
            ps.setString(7, song);

            ps.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            if (((se.getErrorCode() == 30000) && ("23505".equals(se.getSQLState())))) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Could not insert record into ITEM; dup primary key: " + itemCode);
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Could not add row to ITEM table: " + itemCode + " " + se.getCause());
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Could not add row to ITEM table: " + itemCode);
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("Added item to ITEM table: " + itemCode);

        return new itemBean(itemCode, song, artist,category,
                description, songURL, rating);            
    }

    public static itemBean addItem(itemBean item){
        Connection connection = DbConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps;
        // insert the new row into the table
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ITEM VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            ps.setString(1, item.getItemCode());
            ps.setString(2, item.getSong());
            ps.setString(3, item.getCategory());
            ps.setString(5, item.getDesc());
            ps.setString(6, item.getSongURL());
            ps.setString(7, item.getRating());

            ps.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            if (((se.getErrorCode() == 30000) && ("23505".equals(se.getSQLState())))) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Could not insert record into ITEM; dup primary key: " + item.getItemCode());
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Could not add row to ITEM table: " + item.getItemCode() + " " + se.getCause());
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Could not add row to ITEM table: " + item.getItemCode());
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("Added item to ITEM table: " + item.getItemCode());

        // return the  item object
        return item;
    }

    public ArrayList<itemBean> getAllItem(){

        ArrayList<itemBean> items = new ArrayList<itemBean>();

        Statement statement = DbConnection.getNewStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        String itemCode = "";
        String song = "";
        String artist = "";
        String category = "";
        String description = "";
        String songURL = "";
        String rating = "";

        try {

            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
                    "SELECT itemCode, song, artist, category, description, songURL, rating FROM ITEM ORDER BY itemCode");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                itemCode = resultSet.getString("itemCode");
                song = resultSet.getString("song");
                artist = resultSet.getString("artist");
                category = resultSet.getString("category");
                description = resultSet.getString("description");
                songURL = resultSet.getString("songURL");
                rating = resultSet.getString("rating");

                itemBean item = new itemBean(itemCode, song, artist, category, description, songURL, rating);
                items.add(item);
                System.out.println("Found item in Item table: " + itemCode);
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Could not exicute SQL statement in: " + "ItemDB.getAllItems()");
            System.out.println("ERROR: Could not exicute SQL statement: " + se);
            return null;
        }

        return items;

    }

    public itemBean getItem(String pcode){
        itemBean item = new itemBean();
        item.setItemCode(pcode);

        String query = "SELECT itemName, catalogCategory, description, imageUrl"
                + " FROM ITEM WHERE ITEM.itemCode =  " + pcode;
        Statement statement = DbConnection.getNewStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            while (resultSet.next()) {

                item.setSong(resultSet.getString("song"));
                item.setSong(resultSet.getString("artist"));
                item.setCategory(resultSet.getString("category"));
                item.setDesc(resultSet.getString("description"));
                item.setSongURL(resultSet.getString("songURL"));
                item.setRating(resultSet.getString("rating"));

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return item;
    }
}
```

DbConnection file: this is where the database is intialized however it is not connecting

```
package my.pack;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;



     public class DbConnection {



            private static String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
            private static String schemaName = "assignment4";
            private static String dbUsername = "root";
            private static String dbPassword = "888888";
            private static Connection connection;

            public DbConnection() {
                try {
                    // load the DB driver
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    // get a DB connection
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL + schemaName , dbUsername, dbPassword);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Driver not found");
                    connection = null;

                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Could not create DB connection");
                }

            }

            public static Statement getNewStatement() {
                Statement statement;
                try {
                    if (connection == null) {
                        Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "ERROR: Problem with DB connection: ");
                        System.out.println("ERROR: Problem with DB connection:");
                        return null;
                    }
                    /* Creating a statement object that we can use for running
                     * SQL statements commands against the database.*/
                    statement = connection.createStatement();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Could not create SQL statement object: " + e);
                    statement = null;
                }
                return statement;
            }

            public static Connection getConnection() {
                if (connection == null) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "ERROR: Problem with DB connection: ");
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Problem with DB connection:");
                    return null;
                }
                return connection;
            }

            public static void closeConnection() {
                if (connection != null) {
                    try {
                        connection.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: And you've indicated the wrong line as it appears that this, `Statement statement = DbConnection.getNewStatement();` is likely the offending line, no?

Comment: I added the DbConnection file in. I have a database set up with the correct connection to it however I am still not able to access the database because of the null error. And I cant figure out why it is null

Comment: Which line is `collection.java:29`?

Comment: it is the try{ statement.execute("Create Table ...")

Comment: So I was wrong, it is `statement` that is null. Have you used your debugger to trace execution to see why this is so?

Comment: Yes I have tried but I can't find why to be honest

Comment: The statement and the connection are both null. Which the statement is reliant on the connection if I'm not mistaken.